# Pasar datos de javascript a php usando ajax al recargar la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, hash

Buena .
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<head>
<script src="./jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jash = window.location.hash;
var url = "datos.php";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {tuVariable:jash},
    success: exitoso
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

El cual se supone que obtiene el

> hash

de esta url

```
/src/list.html#access_token=533b45555555acf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3
```

y luego lo manda el contenido de la variable

> jash

Al archivo  **datos.php** El cual contiene:

```
<?php
$url = isset($_POST['tuVariable']) ? $_POST['tuVariable'] : '';
echo $url;
```

Lo cual no me funciona ya que no refleja ningún resultado 
espero su ayuda y gracias por su tiempo .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás invirtiendo el orden , el clave valor de `JQuery` de data dentro de `Ajax` es `{ clave : valor}`  , desde `PHP` se accede a `clave` , entonces debería ser

```
var jash = window.location.hash;
var url = "datos.php";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {tuVariable:jash},
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);// return data php
});
```

Comment: Lo intente y recargue la pagina y no obtengo ningún resultado

Comment: si lo revise y no da ningún error

Comment: al parecer no ejecuta el archivo "datos.php" ya que solo uso la recarga de la pagina para mandar la variable . me pregunto si existe alguna manera de lograrlo

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions actualicé mi respuesta con todo el código ajax, ¿aún sigue sin funcionar ? al actualizar la página y tenga el `hash` en la `url`, retornará por consola dicho valor.

Comment: Nada amigo no da ningun resultado